# ObservableQueue empty when trying to dequeue

Tags: c#, wpf, queue

I've implemented my own ObservableQueue in this way:

```
public class ObservableQueue<T> : Queue<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableQueue() : base() { }
        public ObservableQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }
        public ObservableQueue(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }

        public virtual new T Enqueue(T item)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                base.Enqueue(item);
            }
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);

            return item;
        }

        public virtual new T Dequeue()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                var item = base.Dequeue();
                return item;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, T item)
        {
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                action
                , item
                , item == null ? -1 : 0)
            );

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string proertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(proertyName));
        }
    }
```

I subscribe to the queue in MainWindow:

```
paths.CollectionChanged += Process;
```

When a file is added to a specific folder, I enqueue:

```
private void FileCreated(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
      {
          try
           {
                paths.Enqueue(currentPath);
           } catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
           {
               string messageBoxText = exception.Message;
               MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK;
               System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, "Error", button);
          } 
       }
```

This triggers the CollectionChanged on the queue, and I run this in that:

```
private async void Process(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var currentPath = paths.Dequeue();
            await UploadFile(currentPath);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            try
            {
                 MoveFile(currentPath, outputFolderPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentPath));
             } catch (IOException IOE)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(IOE.StackTrace);
            }
       }
```

But I receive the following error when trying to dequeue:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Queue empty.'

I can't seem to figure out how it is possible for the queue to be empty?

I also get the following exception once in a while:

> Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource)
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dequeue()    at
>   Program.Utilities.ObservableQueue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dequeue()    at
>   Program.MainWindow+d__11.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_1(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: Could it be that the event handler is registered more than once? Only the first call will then be able to dequeue.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to provide a good answer. That said: IMHO you should implement your `ObservableQueue<T>` by inheriting `ObservableCollection<T>` and not `Queue<T>`. It's much easier to implement queue semantics on an existing observable collection type than it is to implement collection-changed semantics on an existing queue type.

Comment: I've tried to add a bit more of my code, and a new exception I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is incomplete as we don't get to see *what else* you're doing with the queue, so I'm just guessing here. Could it be that your usage of "async void" as the attached event handler is making Process() run asynchronously while you keep mutating your queue, thereby making this code interleave as the thread pool sees fit in a highly non-deterministic manner?

Comment: I'm not doing anything else with the queue, I've added another exception I receive once in a while. I think you might be right, how can I fix it? I use async to be able to wait for the upload.